# Lotus string illegal array bound

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

If use number can work

```
Dim tablelabels(9) As String
```

But I need use variable [count] ,[count] is number,because there is no fixed value

```
 Dim tablelabels(count) As String   <----
        n=0
        While Not (doc Is Nothing)
            tablelabels(n) = doc.GetItemValue ("Reply")(0)
            n=n+1
            Set doc = view.GetNextDocument (doc)
        Wend
```

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: friendly reminder: Please upvote the answer of Rob and give him the "accepted" checkmark, as it is the correct answer. If you do not know what it means, ask in a comment... Upvotes and accepted- checkmarks award points. Point equal to reputation. And if you do not take part in this part of the community then soon there will be no more answers for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
Dim tablelabels() As String
ReDim tablelabels(count)
```